# Authorize Roles Controller Attribute not working in ASP Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Authorize Attribute not working in ASP Core 2.2 when placed on top of a controller. I have my startup.cs configured like this.

```
        //Add Claims
        services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User>, UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User, Role>();

        //Add Context
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddDbContext<DbContext>();
        services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(
            config =>
            {
                config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            }
            )
            .AddRoles<Role>()
            .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<Role>>()
            .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap3)
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DbContext>();


        //Add MVC
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        services.AddAuthorization();
        services.AddAuthentication();
```

The UserClaimsPrincipalFactory works as it should and I'm able to access the claims in the view via UserManager and filter links based on the role in the claims.

But when I do this on the controller.

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
      return View();
    }
```

It doesn't work and I get access denied despite having the required roles in identity. Is this a known bug and has anyone managed to get role attributes working in ASP Core 2.2?

Comment: the order you add the services matters

Comment: Still getting access denied. Authorize is working fine but once add administrator role I get the access denied error.

Comment: is the administrator assigned to that role in the database?

Comment: Yes. I get the role via userclaims for filtering links via User. Roles = "Administrator" is not working. Debugging the User in the controller shows he has no claims after logging in but during login MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory works well & claims are present. Shouldn't the identity scope returned be assigned & persisted after startup?

Comment: check the database. Claims work differently in .net core

Comment: Roles in the database are working okay via role manager. Why it's not being assigned to HttpContext.User I'm failing to figure out. Roles should work out of the box.

Comment: Is their a user roles table? is the user id and the role id in it?, put the data up

Comment: Yes with role id's assigned to user id's.

Comment: ok let me check my code and ill get back to you later. can you upload userclaims principle factory and check the order you are calling these services.

Comment: have you debugged and looked the the inner exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gotten Roles based on claims working in ASP Core 2.2. Roles without claims aren't working (this could be fixed in ASP Core 3.0).

You need to add values to the RoleClaim & UserClaim tables after creating Roles (Role table) and Adding users to those roles (UserRole table).

Edit...

Basically add users to roles & use the claimtypes.role in your IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory to return a role or add userclaim roles manually using usermanager & rolemanager.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Add Claims
    services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User>, 
    UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User, Role>();

    //these should be move AddMvc
    services.AddAuthorization();
    services.AddAuthentication();

    //Add Context
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    services.AddDbContext<DbContext>();
    services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(
        config =>
        {
            config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        }
        )
        .AddRoles<Role>()
        .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<Role>>()
        .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap3)
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DbContext>();


    //Add MVC
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

Comment: Still getting Access Denied I have tried all sorts of arrangment. Authorize is working fine but once I add the role = "Administrator" I get access denied.